# How to alter a table without having null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a table in sql with 20 rows inserted.In future it may need to add a another column.

In case of adding column values for the particular column will starts from the 21 line,previous rows values in particular column will be null.

I don't want to have null values on those rows.How can i alter the table for that.

Comment: You need to set a default value for that newly added column.

Comment: values for thatcolumn must be enterable .... not by default thts why i m having this dought

Comment: What's the datatype of that column?

Comment: I think there are two choices: 1) having default value in that column for the previously added rows (if you want that column to be NOT NULL) 2) having NULL value in that column for the previously added rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two steps

1 Alter the table

```
Alter table table_name add column new_col datatype
```

2 Update that column into some default value

```
Update table_name set new_col='some value'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it in this way:

```
alter table tbl_sample add COLUMN sampleadd_column VARCHAR(50) default 'just a sample';
```

this should work for you;